# ER relational Database coding containg weak entity

Tags: sql, database, entity, relationship, entity-relationship

So I'm designing a relational database that involves movies, theatres, stands that sell products/souvenirs. Here is the part of the issue that is confusing me:

"...

A movie theatre consists of an identifier, name, address (street,
city, province), and the total number of screens in the theatre.

...

A concession stand is a kiosk that sells products in theatres. The database records the type of concession stand: either food or souvenir (but not both). Products consists of a unique ’stock keeping unit’ (SKU) identifier, the name of the product, the category (e.g., candy, souvenir, popcorn, beverage, toy), and the price of the product (in CAD). Every concession stand must contain at least one product. Concession stands are located only in theatres, and a theatre can have many concession stands within it.

..."

Now I know that concession stand is a weak entity and it has 2 relationships: one with products entity and one with theatre entity. Now both the relationships are going to need to use the type of stand + the primary key of either of the 2 other entities: IS from theatre and SKUID from product.

```
create table HasStand(
    TheatreID integer not null,
    type varchar(20) not null check (type = 'food' or type = 'souvenir'), 
    primary key (TheatreID, type),
    foreign key (TheatreID) references Theatre (ID) on delete cascade
);

create table StandSells(
    ProductID integer not null,
    type varchar(20) not null check (type = 'food' or type = 'souvenir'),  
    primary key (ProductID, type),
    foreign key (ProductID) references Products (SKUID) on delete cascade
);
```

It says that a theatre can have many concession stands i.e. multiple stands that are food and/or multiple stands that are souvenir.

My question is: How can I find out where was a certain product sold? at which theatre? I know I can use the product SKUID to find out type of stand and use the  theatreID to find that stand with that type but I have a situation here where a theatre might have 2 food stands so using the SKUID I find out oit is a food type stand and when I use the TheatreID i find out that there are 2 stands that are food type thus hitting a dead end; i cant find out which one of them sold that item?

p.s. I cannot use a unique IDs for the concession stands at all, only type.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following tables assuming you really can't use a ConcessionStand unique entity. The solution uses the receipt for the sale to track back to the theater and ConcessionStandType but still isn't quick perfect. In other words once a sell is made a ReceiptId gets associated to the respective place it was pulled from using the unique ProductSKUId.

NOTE: I am also assuming each stand has unique product SKUs

```
Theater
   TheaterId - PrimaryKey
   ...other attributes as appropriate
Product
   ProductSKUId - PrimaryKey
   ...other attributes as appropriate
ConcessionStandInventory
   TheaterID - ForeignKey
   ProductSKUId - ForeignKey
   ConcessionTypeID - ForeignKey
   ReceiptId nullable
Receipt
   ReceiptId - PK
   TheaterID
   ProductSKUId 
   ConcessionTypeID
ConcessionType
   ConcessionTypeID
   ConcessionTypeDesc
```